# Pivot Different Prices for the Same Item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a need to show different prices for the same product where the client wants to understand discrepancies in same region. The source table looks like below

| Item | Brand | Concept | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00A | A | Alpha | 1 |
| 00B | A | Alpha | 1 |
| 00B | A | Alpha | 2 |
| 00B | A | Beta | 3 |
| 00A | B | Alpha | 1 |
| 00B | B | Alpha | 1 |
| 00B | B | Beta | 2 |
| 00B | B | Alpha | 3 |

The output I am trying to achieve is a little complicate but can be simplified if we only focus on Brand A so please consider i am pivoting for Brand A only. Result Needed is

| Item | Alpha |  | Beta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00A | 1 | Null | Null |
| 00B | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for conditional aggregation?

```
select item, brand,
       max(case when concept = 'Alpha' and seqnum = 1 then price end) as alpha_price_1,
       max(case when concept = 'Alpha' and seqnum = 2 then price end) as alpha_price_2,
       max(case when concept = 'Beta' and seqnum = 1 then price end) as alpha_price_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item, brand, concept order by price) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by item, brand;
```